# Multiple arrays loop shell

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, dynamic

I have a problem building a "dynamic" array.

First of all I create an array to generate a list of names of files:

```
declare -a pgidarr=`run "select partition_id from ETL.PARTITION_GROUP_MEMBER where partition_group_id=${PGID}"`
for i in ${pgidarr[@]}
do
ARRLOOP=$i
PAID=`run "select LPAD('${ARRLOOP}',2,'0')"` #LPAD the partition ID
FILENAME=ABCD_${PAID}_000000.txt
```

Now in the same loop I want to create a NEW array

```
trigarrat=("${trigarrat[@]}" $FILENAME)
```

But when I run it doens't replace $FILENAME

On Google I can't find much about arrays and variables, anyone could please help me? ;)
Thanks!
Alex

bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.17(1)-release

Comment: You could probably use `PAID=$(printf "%.2d" $i)` to avoid going to the DB just for number formatting.

Comment: You're not initializing `pgidarr` properly; it's a coincidence that the only element of the array is split into words after you expand the array without quoting it. `declare -a pgidarr=( $( run ... ) )`, then `for i in "${pgidarr[@]}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `+=` to append elements to `trigarrat`:

```
declare -a pgidarr=`run "select partition_id from ETL.PARTITION_GROUP_MEMBER where partition_group_id=${PGID}"`
trigarrat=()
for i in ${pgidarr[@]}
do
    ARRLOOP=$i
    PAID=`run "select LPAD('${ARRLOOP}',2,'0')"` #LPAD the partition ID 
    FILENAME=ABCD_${PAID}_000000.txt
    trigarrat+=($FILENAME)
done
```

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters